# Can I set extension policies locally from the registry?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension and I added a managed_schema to define a property (SomeSetting) so I can set it via a policy.

```
manifest.json:
"storage": { "managed_schema": "schema.json" }

schema.json:
"properties": { "SomeSetting": { "type": "string" } }
```

I can see SomeSetting in chrome://policy/ but I have no idea how to set the value.  Apparently I can do this at HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\3rdparty\extensions... but I tried and it never is shown as set in chrome://policy/.

Does anyone know if this is suppose to work?  Does it have to be HKCU instead?  Or do I need Active Directory because setting values locally via the registry is not supported?

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-policy-for-extensions

Answer (score 3):

I had a hard time figuring this out.  The documentation is not all that clear.

In order to get your schema to work you need to add a registry entry for "SomeSetting".

Go to the following item in your registry (create the necessary items):

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\3rdparty\extensions\aaaaaaaaaaaaaa\policy
```

where aaaaaaaaaaaaaa is your extension ID from chrome://extensions

Right-click on "policy" and create a new string value:

```
Name: SomeSetting
Data: "some value"
```

Go back to Chrome and reload chrome://policy/

The new policy should appear.

From your extension, you can access the value like this:

```
chrome.storage.managed.get("SomeSetting", function(setting_val) {
   console.debug(setting_val);
});
```

I'm not sure if this requires Active Directory to work.

Answer (score 0):

It was mentioned in [Alternative Extension Distribution Options](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions) that:

> Google Chrome supports the following extension installation methods:
>
> - Using a preferences JSON file (for Mac OS X and Linux only)
> - Using the Windows registry (for Windows only)

More information regarding other mechanisms on extensions distribution options can be found in the documentation.