# Configure chrome extension without making custom versions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, microsoft-edge-extension

I have a Chrome, Firefox and Edge extension that I want to configure to use a different api url depending on who is using it.

I don't want to create a new version of the extension every time with a different url.

What options do I have to do this? Ideally it would be set for a whole network of users instead of each user having to configure it.

I can think of a few ways:

1. Communicate with a native app (complex)
2. Use a few DNS addresses that could be set in the local network

Are there more options?

Comment: Use [managed storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/storage), here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49386538).

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, I think that's the answer! Please post as such and I will accept it